# Unchangeable element width HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I have a table and I've set the `<td>` tag width  = 60px 
but if I put a string, its width increases! 
How can I make it absolutely fix? While if this will be little for a string only its height increases, not its width.
I want to have no width change in my table and put several tables under each
other as seems they are just one table.

```
<td  style=" width="50px">
```

What shall I do to have a table  with this property?

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be using `<table>` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<col>` tag and set the `table-layout:fixed` style on the `<table>`

```
<table class="tableFixedCell">
    <col width="50px" />
    <tr>
        <td>content here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table.tableFixedCell { 
  table-layout:fixed; 
}
table.tableFixedCell td { 
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```